# Problem displaying a local image that i access from a JSON file in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm rendering out data using flatlist and renderItem from a JSON file I've made, but can't seem to show the local image that I have added to the JSON file.

```
this is how im showing the data from each item

 renderItem({item}) {
    const handlePress = () => {
        this.props.onPress(item);
    }
    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableHighlight 
            onPress={handlePress} 
            >
            <>
                <Image source={item.img}/>
                <Text>{item.name}</Text>
            </>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    );
}

 This is how im writing the img path in my json file

    "img":"require('../assets/images/legends/bangalore/bangalore-half.png')",
```

Trying to read what works online and came to this, But still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

try adding source= {{uri: item.img}}